# ssh-add in script has no effect on user - have to redo ssh-add

Tags: ssh

I am running ssh-add in a setup script:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/<some_key>
```

Problem is that I have to redo `ssh-add` for each key when logging in for the first time.

In the same script I setup `ssh-agent.service` before `ssh-add`

Service:

```
sudo cat << EOF > /etc/systemd/user/ssh-agent.service
[Unit]
Description=SSH authentication agent

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-agent -a %t/ssh-agent.socket -D
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
EOF

    systemctl --user enable ssh-agent.service
    systemctl --user start ssh-agent.service

    echo export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/ssh-agent.socket" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Do you know how to `ssh-add` so I dont have to redo each key the first time I login?

Comment: `ssh-add` without any arguments should load all your keys

Comment: Thanks, but it does not

Comment: @Panki `ssh-add` without arguments only loads one key per key type, using the default key file names. If OP has e.g. one key for each customer, that is not going to work.

Comment: Isn't `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` bound to the lifetime of the login? That's going to require a new ssh-add each session. Maybe put the agent socket into a more permanent location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vanilla OpenSSH `ssh-agent` is intended to run the duration of a single login session only, and has no way to persist loaded keys beyond that. If you are used to e.g. MacOS's keyring-enhanced SSH agent, this might be a bit of a disappointment.

However, the `gpg-agent` of the GnuPG suite can optionally also work as a SSH agent, and can persist keys beyond a single session, but has its own passphrase requirements to secure the persisted keys.